# Use Powershell to match and print specific column from output

Tags: powershell, split, chocolatey, select-string

I want to fetch a specific column from an output of a command. Can someone please suggest what is the best way to do it?

The command used is - `choco list -lo` which gives the output as

```
Chocolatey v0.10.15
chocolatey 0.10.15
erlang 22.3
rabbitmq 3.8.11
3 packages installed.
```

And from the given output the only required value is `3.8.11` which is the version of `rabbitmq`.

I have already tried this but it does not work - `choco list -lo | Select-String -Pattern "rabbit" | %{ $_.Split(' ')[1]; }`

Can someone suggest how can we do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
choco list -lo | 
    Select-String -Pattern "rabbitmq (.+)" | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

Output of `Select-String` is a [`MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) object, so you need to query its members to get the matched value.

I'm using a group `(.+)` to enable extraction of the version number without further string operations. The groups value is then read in the `ForEach-Object` <sup>1</sup> script block through `$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value`. In this expression the index 1 specifies the first group (index 0 would specify the whole match).

---

[1] `ForEach-Object` is abbreviated by `%`

Comment: In the answer, it is `.+` but in the explanation, you have mentioned `.*`, which one is more accurate? I am assuming it to be `*.`. Although, I was able to get the required output from both of them.

Comment: @Ismail `.*` matches any character, zero or more times and `.+` matches any character, one or more times. I think the latter is more correct because we are expecting at least one character for the version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no comma to split on based on what you posted. It's a space...

I don't have choco installed, because I don't have a use case for it. So, a pseudo list is being:

Option1:

```
Clear-Host
$ChocoList = @'
Chocolatey v0.10.15
chocolatey 0.10.15
erlang 22.3
rabbitmq 3.8.11
'@ -Split "`n"

$ChocoList | 
ForEach {
    (
        $PSItem | 
        Select-String -Pattern 'rabbitmq'
    ) -Split (' ')
}
# Results
<#
rabbitmq
3.8.11
#>
```

Option2

```
([regex]::Matches($ChocoList,'rabbitmq.*').Value -split ' ')
# Results
<#
rabbitmq
3.8.11
#>
```

Upadated as per my comment back to yours -  Option1:

```
Clear-Host
$ChocoList = @'
Chocolatey v0.10.15
chocolatey 0.10.15
erlang 22.3
rabbitmq 3.8.11
'@ -Split "`n"

($ChocoList | 
ForEach {
    (
        $PSItem | 
        Select-String -Pattern 'rabbitmq'
    ) -Split (' ')
})[1]
# Results
<#
3.8.11
#>
```

Updated as per my comment back to yours - Option2

```
([regex]::Matches($ChocoList,'rabbitmq.*').Value -split ' ')[1]
# Results
<#
3.8.11
#>
```

Comment: Thanks, @postanote, my requirement is to get only the version nothing else. So the first solution does the trick for me.

Comment: Each will get the version. You just have to select it by the index number. Meaning, just add [1] to the even of either one. as updated. All presented responses are doing the same thing.